# Firebase + Google cloud storage: Handling files of 1MB+ without stalling

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I've run into a curious problem:

Basically I'm making a Firebase Cloud function where when someone uploads a file then that file is sent via email or API to somewhere else.

Everything works for tiny files (100K-ish), if slow, but anything above 1MB (haven't  tested the exact size) stalls. Doesn't give any errors in the Firebase log, the function just never completes.

Here's the relevant code:

```js
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')({
    projectId: 'bilagskortet',
    keyFilename: './service-account-key.json'
});


const returnBase64 = (fileFullPathAndName) => {
    console.log("Fetching file...")
    // Downloads the file
    return Storage
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .file(fileFullPathAndName)
        .download()
        .then((data) => {
            const file = {};
            file.file = new Buffer(data[0]).toString('base64');
            return file;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Didn't get file:", error);
        });

}
```

This is used together with two other Promises to get everything about the file needed for the email:

```js
 Promise
        .all([  

            StorageFile.returnDownloadURL(attachementRef)
                .then(url => {
                    console.log("AttachmenetLink is: ")
                    console.log(typeof url);
                    console.log(url);
                    email.attachementLink = url
                }) 
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error, didn't get link: ")
                    console.error(error)
                }),

            StorageFile.returnMetaData(attachementRef)
                .then(metadata => {
                    console.log("Content type:")
                    console.log(metadata.contentType);
                    file.contentType = metadata.contentType;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Didn't get the metadata")
                    console.error(error);
                }),

            StorageFile.returnBase64(attachementRef)
                .then(data => {
                    console.log("File is: ")
                    console.log(typeof data);
                    console.log(data);
                    file.data = data.file;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error, didn't get file: ")
                    console.error(error)
                })

            ])

        .then(allData => {
            // Define and send email with attachement (cut for brevity)
        }).catch(error => 
            console.error(error)
        )
```

As I've said, the code works well if the file is tiny. Times out and dies if the file is for example a 1.7MB image (.png)

Anyone know what might be going on?

Last thing that's logged is the "AttachmentLink" and "Content Type" ones, and last thing in the StorageFile.returnBase64 function is "Fetching file..."

Comment: OK, debugged some more. With a higher memory limit (1GB(!) instead of 256MB) and higher timeout (120s instead of 60s) one of the functions actually completed.

So then it's a question of **why would this be so memory and resource heavy**? All it's doing is downloading a 1.7MB file, converting it to base64, and passing all that to SparkPost. It also spent a looong time doing all that.

Comment: Hi. got the same issue. where did you increase your cloud function memory limits ?

Comment: ok I found it on https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list